# How can I convert a char into an int in C, so that a = 0, b = 1, and c = 2?

Tags: c

I want my program to convert characters into integers, but not into their ASCII equivalents.
For example, `'A'` should equal 0, not 65, while `'B'` should equal 1.
Then I want to add that number to an ASCII character and convert that value back to a `char`.

Comment: Why is `c==3` and not `c==2`?

Comment: Because it starts at 0.

Comment: Yes... a=0, b=1, c=2

Comment: Be exact. `'A'` is uppercase, `'b'` is lowercase, they have different codepoint ranges in ASCII.

Comment: In general, just subtract `'A'` (or `'a'`).

Comment: If you rely on ASCII then consulting [an ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) might help. Think a little, if you subtract two values (like e.g. `65` from `66`) what is the result?

Comment: Try atoi(c) - 'A'

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thanks!

Comment: `int anInt = toupper(aChar)-'A';`

Comment: Subtracting only works on ASCII and those character sets that have adjacent letter code points. Otherwise, you might prefer a lookup table: `int lookup[] = { ['A'] = 0, [a] = 0, /* ... */ }`

Comment: int number = 'C' - 'A'

Comment: @Aconcagua I can't do that.

Comment: @Anonymous *Why* can't you do that? I can't imagine that memory (1024 bytes at most, assuming 8-bit char) would really be the issue - if still, you could reduce by setting unsigned short or even unsigned char as array data type...

Comment: @Aconcagua Well, I am taking a course, and it **does not** allow that.

Comment: @Anonymous Well, then I'd go with the subtraction approach...

Comment: @Aconcagua That's *exactly* what I did!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char test = 'C';
int num = test - 'A';
// result: 2 with ASCII and any other encoding
// having the uppercase letters in sequence
```

Answer (score 5):

Subtracting is nice and easily implemented, but it only works on ASCII and all those other character sets that have adjacent letter code points (which is the vast majority).

If you must fear the code might be running on machines with a character set not applying to this condition, you might prefer a lookup table:

```
int lookup[] = { ['a'] = 0, ['A'] = 0, /* ... */ };
```

Don't forget to check the array bounds if using arbitrary numbers. Be aware that the unspecified values in between are initialised to 0, too, so if you need to differenciate, you might add one to each explicitly specified value (`['a'] = 1`), add appropriate error handling for 0 and otherwise subtract 1 again...

Comment: uv'd for completeness. This will almost never be needed in practice, but e.g. *EBCDIC* is such a "nasty" encoding with "holes" between uppercase letters.

Comment: @FelixPalmen What do you mean?

Comment: @toyotasupra just an example for a weird text encoding where letters are not all "in sequence", [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Code_page_layout). If you need your code to be portable to strange systems like that, this is the answer for you :)

Answer (score 4):

Check wheather the letter is uppercase or not and then assign the value:

```
int num;
char ch = 'C'
if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
   num = ch - 'A'
else
   num = ch - 'a'
```